# HTML DOM Tree traversal using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dom

I have an HTML DOM Structure like this. I would like to access the text inside "ctitle", "daytime" and "vv". I am at the `<button>` position. As in $(this) = button:

**NOTE: The DOM elements inside `<ul>....</ul>` are repeated**

```
<ul id="classes">
  <li class="ctitle" />
  <li class="cschedule">
    <table>
     <tr/>
     <tr>
      <td class="vv" />
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="daytime">
     <tr>
    </table>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my effort but none of them are working.

```
ctitle= $(this).closest("#classes").find(".ctitle").text();
vv = $(this).closest("#classes").find("table .vv").text();
daytime = $(this).closest("#classes").find("table .daytime").text()
```

Comment: If you start of with valid HTML, it's probably easier, and why would you search for an ID, it's unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example html, and assuming there's some structure in how it's generated and so the order is always the same:

```
var cschedule = $(this).parent().prev()
var vv = cschedule.find('.vv')
var daytime = cschedule.find('.daytime')
var ctitle = cschedule.prev()
```

Comment: i have a repitition of `ctitle` element inside my `<ul>` so using your approach is also giving me the text of other `ctitles`

Comment: Same with other elements that is `.vv` and `.daytime`

Comment: Ok well this changes things, something's not right, if elements with certain format repeat then maybe they should be items themselves? Anyway, I updated my answer based on this update, it assumes that the formatting is predictable, hopefully there are no more surprises in your html :)

Comment: yes it works for the first element but doesn't for the second repition. Here is my page:
http://i.cs.hku.hk/~hsbashir/Project_Work/Timetable_schedule/schedule_portal.html